# regex that selects lines containing a phone number

Tags: regex

I did my code for regular expression that selects lines containing a phone number. I have to create an expression for a phone number, but it may have - or . in between the numbers, and it may or may not have an extension. I couldn't figure out and didn't submitted as my homework...I just want to know how its done right because I might have it on the Exam at the end of the semester.

718-951-5000, 
718.951.5000,
(718)-951-5000

My code

```
     "(^(\([2-9]\\d{2}\)|[2-9]\\d{2})[- .]?\d{3}[- .]?\\d{4}$)|(^(\([2-9]\\d{2}\)|[2-9]\\d{2})[- .]?\d{3}[- .]?\\d{4}[xX]\\d{1,4}$)"
```

My Error
*RETest1.java:4: error: illegal escape character*

```
                  "(^(\([2-9]\\d{2}\)|[2-9]\\d{2})[- .]?\\d{3}[- .]?\\d{4}$)|(^(\([2-9]\\d{2}\)|[2-9]\\d{2})[- .]?\\d{3}[- .]?\\d{4}[xX]\\d{1,4}$)"
                       ^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[- .]?\d{3}[- .]?`

You forgot the second escape `\` on the `\d`

Should be:
`"(^(\([2-9]\\d{2}\)|[2-9]\\d{2})[- .]?\\d{3}[- .]?\\d{4}$)|(^(\([2-9]\\d{2}\)|[2-9]\\d{2})[- .]?\\d{3}[- .]?\\d{4}[xX]\\d{1,4}$)"`

Comment: @yulana I was checking the regex and it seems to be buggy to me on [regexr](http://www.regexr.com). I'd try building it there first and then transposing it to Java.

Comment: I'm using codelab software and its not that when I test my code because it keep giving me errors

Comment: @yulana What do you mean? When you test it in "codelab" it works?

Comment: not really it keep telling me I'm having errors....codelab software thats where I do my work.....

Comment: Post the full error and your code on the question and I'll be glad to help.

Comment: this is what I'm getting when I run my code in Codelab -----> RETest1.java:4: error: illegal escape character
                      "(^(\([2-9]\\d{2}\)|[2-9]\\d{2})[- .]?\\d{3}[- .]?\\d{4}$)|(^(\([2-9]\\d{2}\)|[2-9]\\d{2})[- .]?\\d{3}[- .]?\\d{4}[xX]\\d{1,4}$)"
                             ^

Answer (score 1):

It might not be the prettiest, but here is one that works:

```
"^((\\([2-9]\\d{2}\\)|[2-9]\\d{2})(-\\d{3}-\\d{4}|\\.\\d{3}\\.\\d{4})([Xx] ?\\d{1,4})?)$"
```